# Adding a data to a specific cell in a table

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to add a data to a specific cell on a table (table is not required if there is any way to a add the data to a specific location in the screen).
I was using datatable but can't figure how to add the wanted data to a specific cell in the row.
the data I want to entre is a time, it works when I press a button it gives the time of pressing in the table and when press it again it gives the time to the next cell to it

Comment: To fill and edit the datatable you should build it dynamically using the concepts of Stateful Widget and setState(). In this way you can build up the table using a List. To update the content of the table you just have to edit the content of the list and call the setState() method.

Comment: that's good, but my problem here is make the button and the table related to each other.
when I press the button, the data automatically go to the cell in datatable and when i press the button again it goes to another cell and go on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.